# Simple SQL query not giving proper results

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

Here's a query i constructed:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM tagResourceName a INNER JOIN 
tagResource b ON a.tagID=b.tagID
```

However, the result is returning values which are not distinct. e.g.

```
Tag Name | Tag ID
pink     |  13
pink     |  13
zoo      |  16
```

Why is that? I'm running this on an Android app btw. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM tagResourceName a 
INNER JOIN tagResource b ON a.tagID=b.tagID
GROUP BY a.tagName, a.tagID
ORDER BY a.tagID
```

Comment: thanks arif. group by solved it. but i still dont get why distinct didnt work?

Comment: DISTINCT works fine in SQLite. I'd guess that there are other columns involved that the OP isn't showing us, that OP's query will not produce a two column result set.

Answer (score 0):

Might one of your tags have trailing spaces?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM tagResourceName a INNER JOIN 
tagResource b ON a.tagID=b.tagID
GROUP BY b.tagName, a.tagID
ORDER BY a.tagID
```